# 'promisify' (async/await) sending a message to Microsoft Teams using pymsteams in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, microsoft-teams

I am sending lots of messages to MS Teams within my Python scripts using the `logging` module. Unfortunately this is quite slow so I would like to add async/await functionality to the messages.

Here is my logger module (somewhat simplified) :

```py
from logging import StreamHandler
import pymsteams

class TeamsHandler(StreamHandler):

    def __init__(self, channel_url):
        StreamHandler.__init__(self)
        self.channel_url = channel_url
        self.client = pymsteams.connectorcard(self.channel_url)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.client.text(msg)
        try:
            self.client.send()
        except:
            print(f"{msg} could not be sent to Teams")
```

which you would then use in a regular script as such :

```py
import logging
from TeamsHandler import TeamsHandler #the module above

my_logger = logging.getLogger('TestLogging')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
my_logger.addHandler(console_handler)

CHANNEL_ID = "https://outlook.office.com/webhook/your-big-number"
teamshandler = TeamsHandler(CHANNEL_ID)
teamshandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s %(message)s'))
teamshandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
my_logger.addHandler(teamshandler)
for i in range(1,100):
    my_logger.error(f"this is an error [{i}]")
    my_logger.info(f"this is an info [{i}]")
do_something_else()
```

How can I make it so that `do_something_else` gets executed immediately (almost) instead of having to wait for 200 messages to make their way to Teams ?

I tried to add some `async` and `await` keywords within the `TeamsHandler` module but no tries were successful so I didn't put them in the question. Happy to get some pointers if not a full solution.

Ideally, the order of the messages should be kept intact as the script progresses.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: Great ! not sure what you can investigate though. There is no issue with the platform itself, I'm just trying to make it suit my needs.

Comment: Could you please post your query [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/tree/4.9)? This would be a better place to get quick resolution of your issue.

Comment: Think it's different though. My stuff is based on the pymsteams library, it's not a bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pymsteams` doesn't support async/await, then adding `async` to your functions won't really help you because you'd still end up calling sync code from `pymsteams`. And even if it did support async/await, it still wouldn't work because you are calling them from inside the Python logging API, which is itself not async. Async/await cannot magically transform sync code into async, the program must use async/await across the board.

But if you need async execution in the sense of just running something in the background, you can use threads instead. For example, create a dedicated thread for logging, such as:

```
class TeamsHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, channel_url):
        super().__init__()
        self.channel_url = channel_url
        self.client = pymsteams.connectorcard(self.channel_url)
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._worker)
        self.thread.start()
        # shutdown the worker at process exit
        atexit.register(self.queue.put, None)

    def _worker(self):
        while True:
            record = self.queue.get()
            if record is None:
                break
            msg = self.format(record)
            self.client.text(msg)
            try:
                self.client.send()
            except:
                print(f"{msg} could not be sent to Teams")

    def emit(self, record):
        # enqueue the record to log and return control to the caller
        self.queue.put(record)
```

Of course, this has the disadvantage that in case of a problem with the logging backend, your program can advance quite ahead of what you see in the logs - but that is always the case when you remove synchronization between logging and execution.

Comment: This is exactly what I need thank you very much. Will give it a try ASAP. In that case I'm not too worried about synchronisation as long as the info gets there eventually. Plus it also outputs to a file in any case. The time to send the messages to teams was killing my execution time.

Comment: @Chapo The thread is a non-daemon thread, so Python will wait for it to finish before the program ends, and in that sense they will indeed get there eventually (provided the program is left to run to completion). You should just be aware that this code still sends the messages one by one, just in a separate thread. So if it takes a long time to send each message and your program is generous with logging, it might take quite some time for the logs to catch up with the program.

Comment: Ok thank you for the details. I'm fine with this as long as it doesn't slow down the execution of the actual script. Waiting at the end when the rest of it is done is fine.

Comment: It won't slow affect execution of the script because the queue is unbounded. The waiting will only occur at interpreter shutdown, after the top-level Python code has finished running.

Comment: And the order of the messages will be respected because the logger module uses only one thread? Or am I mistaken here?

Comment: @Chapo The order will be respected within a handler because there is only one queue, and the queue is FIFO. If you have multiple handlers and want the order respected, you should make the queue and the worker global.

Comment: Great thank you. I'm working with one handler per script basically aobtjats perfect.

Comment: One last question if you have 2 seconds: I think the open thread keeps the process open. Should I have a step where i close the hdler and the tread/queue once my script comes to completion ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217450/discussion-between-chapo-and-user4815162342).

Comment: @Chapo You're right; I've now amended the answer to shutdown the worker at process exit.

Comment: Ended up posting another question for the exit issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812511/python-thread-not-exiting-with-atexit will report here if I get an answer