# python thread not exiting with atexit

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

Here is my script. When I run it in a shell it just hangs indefinitely whereas I would expect it to terminate cleanly.

```py
import logging
from logging import StreamHandler
import pymsteams
import queue
import threading
import atexit


class TeamsHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, channel_url):
        super().__init__()
        self.channel_url = channel_url
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._worker)
        self.thread.start()
        atexit.register(self.queue.put, None)

    def _worker(self):
        while True:
            record = self.queue.get()
            if record is None:
                break
            msg = self.format(record)
            print(msg)

    def emit(self, record):
        # enqueue the record to log and return control to the caller
        self.queue.put(record)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_logger = logging.getLogger('TestLogging')
    my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    my_logger.addHandler(console_handler)

    CHANNEL_ID = "not_used_anyway"
    teamshandler = TeamsHandler(CHANNEL_ID)
    teamshandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s %(message)s'))
    teamshandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    my_logger.addHandler(teamshandler)
    for i in range(1, 2):
        my_logger.error(f"this is an error [{i}]")
        my_logger.info(f"this is an info [{i}]")
```

The `None` record that should be sent by `atexit` (line 28) never arrives so the thread stays open forever.

How to make sure that the program exits cleanly by modifying the `TeamsHandler` only ?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example, without all that URL / logging stuff?

Comment: ask and you shall receive

Comment: I have no solution for your problem, but I have a couple of comments. First, `atexit` handler fires at interpreter exit, not at main thread exit -- so it is never called, because you have a running thread, and interpreter is not exiting. Second, you can add `daemon=True` to your `Thread(...)` constructor, but this will cause the thread to die immediately when main thread exits, no matter did it process all the messages or not.

Answer (score 0):

I got something working, have a look:

```
import queue
import threading


class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        threading.Thread(target=self._worker).start()

    def _worker(self):
        print("starting thread")
        while True:
            record = self.queue.get()
            if record is None:
                print("exiting")
                break
            print(f"Got message: {record}")

    def emit(self, record):
        self.queue.put(record)


class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self._worker = Worker()

    def __del__(self):
        print("Wrapper is being deleted")
        self._worker.emit(None)

    def emit(self, record):
        self._worker.emit(record)

def main():
    worker = Wrapper()
    worker.emit("foo")
    worker.emit("bar")
    print("main exits")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The point here is that when `main` exits, `worker` (which is an instance of `Wrapper`) goes out of scope, and its `__del__` method is called, and it sends stop message to a real worker object.

The results of running this code ("Got message" lines can be in different places, of course):

```
starting thread
main exits
Wrapper is being deleted
Got message: foo
Got message: bar
exiting
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by avysk, the problem is likely that `atexit` handlers fire too late, after the waiting for the non-daemon threads is already (supposed to be) done, which leads to deadlock.

If I were you, I'd just add a call like `TeamsHandler.finish()` at the end of `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, and modify `TeamsHandler` along these lines (untested):

```
_queues = []

class TeamsHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, channel_url):
        super().__init__()
        self.channel_url = channel_url
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._worker)
        self.thread.start()
        _queues.append(self.queue)

    def _worker(self):
        while True:
            record = self.queue.get()
            if record is None:
                break
            msg = self.format(record)
            print(msg)

    def emit(self, record):
        # enqueue the record to log and return control to the caller
        self.queue.put(record)

    @staticmethod
    def finish(self):
        for q in _queues:
            q.put(None)
        del _queues[:]
```

Comment: this is meant to be used as a module unlike the example script so not really practical to have to declare global variables to handle the queues object created by the class.

Comment: @Chapo The global variable is internal, though. The user is just required to call `finish()` when done. (It could also be implemented as a context manager usable with the `with` statement.)

Comment: yes it does work nicely enough in fact my bad. Would have been nicer if it didn't require the actual call to `finish` and "just worked" like the other logging modules but that's life I guess.

Comment: @Chapo avysk's answer provides a "just works" variant, but it's a bit too magical for my taste, as it relies on the GC to close the channel. A version that uses `with` might look nicer, but it'd still require visible cleanup code. A just-works version might create another thread that waits for `threading.main_thread().join()` and then invokes `finish()`, but that just assumes that the main thread is the last to log anything, which might not always be the case. Explicit closing is a compromise that at least makes it clear what's going on.

Comment: I couldn't get that solution to work with my actual use case unfortunately and I'd rather have only one class to follow the logger module spec. Your solution is fine but I don't understand how there is not a function within the `StreamHandler` class that gets called when it gets out of scope. I could then hijack that one instead of relying on an extra `finish` call.

Comment: @Chapo In Python the same object can be referenced by multiple variables and/or containers, so one of them going out of scope doesn't mean that the object will be reclaimed. When the GC determines that the object is no longer reachable, its `__del__` is called, but as you discovered, that tends to be fragile for a number of reasons (internal references by logging itself, circular references).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#dealing-with-handlers-that-block think I might be able to achieve my goal "cleanly" using queuehandler for logging. Will post it as a solution if it does work. Otherwise will validate yours

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the thread ends when the program ends, you should make it a daemon-thread.  Then you don't need any of that `atexit` stuff, which as you found out doesn't work anyway since it doesn't fire early enough.

```py
class TeamsHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, channel_url):
        super().__init__()
        self.channel_url = channel_url
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._worker)
    
        self.thread.setDaemon(True)  # INSERT THIS LINE
    
        self.thread.start()

# ...
```